# Increment variable within for loop

Tags: python, loops, iteration, increment

I am new to Python and am trying to figure out how to address the following issue. I have two lists, list1 looks like this:

```
['10','12','12','23]
```

And list2 looks like this:

```
['15','16','13','15']
```

I also have a dictionary consisting of the following key-values:

```
dictionary = {
'10': 'AATGCGTAAGCTAGCGATAGATGCAACGTT', 
'12': 'GGTCAGAGTTTATCGGTATGTTAGCATGGA', 
'23': 'ATGGGCGCGTATATTAAAGGCGCCGCCCTG'
}
```

The keys in this dictionary consist of those elements in list1. Each element in list1 is also associated with a single element in list2 (in order, such that '10' in list1 is associated with '15' in list2, '12' in list1 with '16' in list2, etc.).

For each element in list1, I would like to take the associated dictionary value, and insert characters into specific positions using the associated element in list2 to determine the positions. So far I've been working on a for loop to do this:

```
for i in list1:
    dict_key = dictionary.get(i)
    pos = int(list2[0])
    full = dict_key[:pos] + '[' + dict_key[pos] + ']' +  dict_key[(pos+1):]
    print(full)
```

I would like my final output to look like this:

```
AATGCGTAAGCTAGC[G]ATAGATGCAACGTT
GGTCAGAGTTTATCGG[T]ATGTTAGCATGGA
GGTCAGAGTTTAT[C]GGTATGTTAGCATGGA
ATGGGCGCGTATATT[A]AAGGCGCCGCCCTG
```

But my output currently looks like this because I am specifically calling for only index 0 from list2:

```
AATGCGTAAGCTAGC[G]ATAGATGCAACGTT
GGTCAGAGTTTATCG[G]TATGTTAGCATGGA
GGTCAGAGTTTATCG[G]TATGTTAGCATGGA
ATGGGCGCGTATATT[A]AAGGCGCCGCCCTG
```

I want to increase the element that's called for in list2 by 1 with each iteration of the loop, but I can't seem to figure it out. Should I define a new variable using range? Any comments will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `for i in list1:` to `for i, pos in zip(list1, list2):` and remove the assignment of `pos` in the second line of the loop. `zip` will let you iterate through both lists at once.

Comment: Thanks for this solution @Randy C! Very simple and does what I wanted, will also be helpful to know in general. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Using [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) is helpful in situations like this - it gives you a tuple containing the position of each element, and the element itself. Note, I've changed your meaning of `i` to mean the element's position rather than the element.

Your variable `dict_key` would probably be better called `dict_value`, since the element in `list1` is actually the key that you are looking up in `dictionary`.

```
for i, el in enumerate(list1):
    dict_value = dictionary.get(el)
    pos = int(list2[i])
    full = dict_value[:pos] + '[' + dict_value[pos] + ']' +  dict_value[(pos+1):]
    print(full)
```

Comment: Also very helpful, thanks @enigma, I had not previously used enumerate.

Answer (score 0):

You can build iterators for your lists (`int(i) for i in list2` for instance iterates `list2`, converting its values to `int` on the way) and use `zip` to read them in pairs.

```
list1 = ['10','12','12','23']
list2 = ['15','16','13','15']

dictionary = {
'10': 'AATGCGTAAGCTAGCGATAGATGCAACGTT', 
'12': 'GGTCAGAGTTTATCGGTATGTTAGCATGGA', 
'23': 'ATGGGCGCGTATATTAAAGGCGCCGCCCTG'
}

for val, pos in zip((dictionary[j] for j in list1), (int(i) for i in list2)):
    full = val[:pos] + '[' + val[pos] + ']' +  val[(pos+1):]
    print(full)
```

Some people would prefer string formatting to build the resulting string

```
full = '{}[{}]{}'.format(val[:pos], val[pos], val[pos+1:])
```

but that's personal taste.

Comment: Thanks @tdelaney, gives me what I want and I now know about list iterators.